# XAMPP MySQL failing to start after WIN 11 Update

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp

Win 11 with an XAMPP installation, everything was running fine. Had to restart the PC and had a Windows update as well. When I come back MySQL will not start up.

This is the error log. I am running it as Admin, not sure what I need to do to fix this.

```
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'E:\barkeeper\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'E:\barkeeper\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.19 started; log sequence number 15569034; transaction id 163623
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from E:\barkeeper\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect file format 'db'
2022-03-24 18:13:12 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it, here is how:

1. Close the Xampp application ( preferably using task Manager)
2. Open `C:\xampp\mysql` folder
3. Rename the data  folder to `data_old`
4. Copy and paste the backup folder named `backup_copy`
5. Rename the `backup_copy` folder to `data`
6. Open `data_old` folder, copy all folders except `mysql` folder, `performance_schema` folder and `phpmyadmin` folder.
7. Go to the newly renamed data folder, paste the folders from step 6 inside.
8. Open the `data_old` folder, copy `ibdata1`
9. Paste it in the `data` folder
10. Start Xampp, everything should be working now.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem after upgrading from Win10 to Win 11, the solution proposed by ***cartzedan*** didn't work for me...

I solved it like this:

- full backup of folder c:\xampp
- uninstalling Xampp
- new installation of Xampp, same version as above
- copy the entire backup folder to the new folder overwriting the files